# android webview display the last seen page

Tags: android, webview, web

I created a simple webview app and it works fine, except that every time I open the app it shows the main page and not the page that I was in last time, just like the regular browser

java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
WebView webView;

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "SharedPreferences";

public static final String PREF_STRING = "http://www.google.com";
  private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
// force web view to open inside application
 webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
 openURL();

}

private void openURL() {
webView.loadUrl(PREF_STRING);


SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("StartPage", 0);
settings.getString("PREF_STRING", "http://www.google.com");
}


@Override
public void onResume() {

webView.loadUrl(mPrefs.getString(PREF_STRING, "http://www.google.com"));

}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
view.loadUrl(url);
return true;
}
}
}
```

xml file

```
<RelativeLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_below="@id/progressbar_Horizontal"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Save the last page inside SharedPreferences and retrieve it onResume()

Comment: check my updated code, I used SharedPreferences to save the last page but it crashes my app.

Comment: Let me look into it.

Comment: Take a look at the example that I added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example of how to save the last visited URL.

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

```
private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview_activity);

    //The web view
    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webViewEx1);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());

    //Load the URL from saved url
    webView.loadUrl(getUrl());

}

public void saveUrl(String url){
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("SP_WEBVIEW_PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString("SAVED_URL", url);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getUrl(){

    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("SP_WEBVIEW_PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
    //If you haven't saved the url before, the default value will be google's page
    return sp.getString("SAVED_URL", "http://google.com");

}

private class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        //Save the last visited URL
        saveUrl(url);
    }


}
```

}

Basically all you have to do is save the last url inside SharedPreferences and retrieve it from there.
Hope it helps.

Comment: essential on turn website into  app using webview